# Adding fractions using classes (Wrong output)

Tags: c++, class, fractions

I previously wrote a program that adds two fractions together and prints the output, simple I know. I originally implemented the program using structs and now I'm trying to re-implement it using classes, not so simple i guess... The problem is whenever I print the output it returns as zeros all across (double zeros for the denominator, I don't know why its doing that either), no matter what numbers I input.

```
Sample output:
Enter First Numerator: 1
Enter First Denominator: 2
Enter Second Numerator: 1
Enter Second Denominator: 4
-------------------------
0/00 + 0/00 = 0/00
```

Please look at my code and tell me what the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
public:
    Fraction()
    {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 0;
    }
public:
    void set(int n, int d) {n = numerator; d = denominator;};
    int getNumerator() {return numerator;};
    int getDenominator() {return denominator;};
    Fraction addTo(Fraction &frac2, Fraction& frac3);
    int print() { cout << numerator << "/" << denominator; return 0;};
};
//Adds the value of the Fraction with the attached "addTo" method with the value of a second   specified Fraction and assigns the result to a third specified Fraction.
Fraction Fraction::addTo(Fraction& frac2, Fraction& addedTo)
{
    frac2.numerator = (numerator * frac2.denominator) + (denominator * frac2.numerator);
    frac2.denominator = (denominator * frac2.denominator);
    frac2.numerator = addedTo.numerator;
    frac2.denominator = addedTo.denominator;
    return addedTo;
}

int main()
{
Fraction frac1, frac2, frac3;
int n1, n2, d1, d2;

//Prompts the user for data and then assigns it to the correct variables.
cout << "Enter First Numerator: ";
cin >> n1;

cout << "Enter First Denominator: ";
cin >> d1;

cout << "Enter Second Numerator: ";
cin >> n2;

cout << "Enter Second Denominator: ";
cin >> d2;

frac1.set(n1, d1);
frac2.set(n2, d2);

frac1.addTo(frac2, frac3);

//Formats output.
cout<< "-------------------------\n"
    << frac1.print() << " + " << frac2.print()<< " = " << frac3.print() << endl;
cout << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you use n1, d1, n2 and d2?

Comment: You should overload `operator+` and `operator+=` instead of using the function.  Otherwise, either make the function static or move it outside the class.

Comment: I don't see where you use the integers to construct or initialise the `Fraction` class, call your set function before the output, but after the input of the integer values have been completed.

Comment: Oh wow, how did not catch that... EDIT: Added that set method, same results.

Comment: Your original set method had `n = numerator` I think that should be `numerator = n` and then the same with the denominator. There are a very other errors, but they have been pointed out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You made a mistake here:

```
int print() { cout << numerator << "/" << denominator; /* why to hell this method returns 0?! */ return 0;};
```

Just write like this:

```
void print() { cout << numerator << "/" << denominator; }; // this method doesn't need to return any value
```

And you made a mistake here:

```
//Formats output.
cout<< "-------------------------\n"
<< frac1.print() << " + " << frac2.print()<< " = " << frac3.print() << endl;
cout << "\n";
```

You can simply write:

```
// Formats output
frac1.print();
std::cout << " + ";
frac2.print();
std::cout << " = ";
frac3.print();
```

Yes, of course you can try to create method that returns fraction as string, but you have to cast int to string then and use stringstream for example, so my idea is easier.

**@EDIT**

You didn't set value of numerators and denominators here:

```
//Prompts the user for data and then assigns it to the correct variables.
cout << "Enter First Numerator: ";
cin >> n1;

cout << "Enter First Denominator: ";
cin >> d1;

cout << "Enter Second Numerator: ";
cin >> n2;

cout << "Enter Second Denominator: ";
cin >> d2;
```

You have to write like this:

```
//Prompts the user for data and then assigns it to the correct variables.
cout << "Enter First Numerator: ";
cin >> n1;
frac1.numerator = n1;

cout << "Enter First Denominator: ";
cin >> d1;
frac1.denominator = d1;

cout << "Enter Second Numerator: ";
cin >> n2;
frac2.numerator = n2;

cout << "Enter Second Denominator: ";
cin >> d2;
frac2.denominator = d2;
```

**@EDIT2**

I have just found a new mistake that you made. You have to write add method like this:

```
//Adds the value of the Fraction with the attached "addTo" method with the value of a second   
specified Fraction and assigns the result to a third specified Fraction.
Fraction Fraction::addTo(Fraction& frac2, Fraction& addedTo)
{
    addedTo.numerator = (numerator * frac2.denominator) + (denominator * frac2.numerator);
    addedTo.denominator = (denominator * frac2.denominator);
    // frac2.numerator = addedTo.numerator; // this line was a mistake because you tried to set result's numerator again
    // frac2.denominator = addedTo.denominator; // the same as above
    return addedTo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced my code with yours but I am still getting zeros for everything.

Comment: Please look again at my post. I edited it.

Comment: In order to do that I would need to change my numerator and denominator variables to public, which i just did, but now when entering 1, 2, 1, 4 it outputs this: 1/2 + 0/0 = 0/0. Could there be something wrong with my addTo method?

Comment: Please see my new edit.

Comment: That did it, thank you for the help and also for adding comments to your corrections. I'm just starting out in c++ so it helps to know what im doing wrong and why as opposed to just getting the right answer!

Comment: @DomBavetta, consider writing an overload for `operator<<` as well. It will allow you to write `cout << frac1 << endl;`